# How to run script on remote windows machines

Tags: windows, remote-access, remote, bash-scripting

I have in my Network some non-domain machines which run Windows Operating System, I need to run some scripts on them remotely, but I don't know how to do that.
If you could recommend anyway to do that.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Have you looked into `psexec` ?

Comment: You tagged this with `bash-scripting`.  Are you trying to run bash scripts on a remote Windows machine?

Comment: yes  squillman I am trying to run a bash script on a remote Windows machine